# python implementation of matlab "d2c" function

Tags: python, matlab, continuous, discrete, system-identification

I'm trying to convert a discrete transfer function to a continuous one (z to s) in python. It works perfectly fine in Matlab:

```
>> H = tf([0.0, 0.00011109058274028799, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],[1.0, -4.746477630953663, 9.128106677145524, -8.893610005776452, 4.389391849996713, -0.8774091162885327],0.1)

H =
 
                        0.0001111 z^4
  ----------------------------------------------------------
  z^5 - 4.746 z^4 + 9.128 z^3 - 8.894 z^2 + 4.389 z - 0.8774
 
Sample time: 0.1 seconds
Discrete-time transfer function.

>> a = d2c(H)

a =
 
  0.0002306 s^4 + 0.009752 s^3 + 0.2071 s^2 + 2.384 s + 11.99
  -----------------------------------------------------------
  s^5 + 1.308 s^4 + 13.53 s^3 + 11.52 s^2 + 6.224 s + 0.1914
```

But there seems to be no implementation in python. Does anyone know where to find one?

Answer (score 0):

Try [harold discretization functions](https://harold.readthedocs.io/en/latest/function_reference.html#discretization)